# CentOS 6.9 : bash: PATH is not a valid identifier

Tags: java, centos

So I am trying to set up the `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` variables for my CentOS 6.9 virtual machine. After installing Java, I did the following:

```
$ vi ~/.bashrc
```

Then in `.bashrc` I added:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Downloads/jdk1.8.0_191
export PATH =$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

When I did

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

I got the bash error saying that `/Downloads/jdk1.8.0_191/bin` is not a valid identifier. I tried commenting out the export PATH part, and with only the export JAVA_HOME it worked. I looked inside the `jdk1.8.0_191` folder, and the `bin` folder does exist in there. I wonder what could cause the problem?

I have read question @45426520 before, and we are probably experiencing similar problems. However, I did not understand half the question, and still really need a solution for the CentOS operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the space between `PATH` and  `=$JAVA_HOME/bin` should solve your issue.

Have a look an the [man page](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/exporth.html) of export. With the space inbewteen. export will only take `PATH`into account and ignore the rest of the line. This rest is interpreted by bash, and here `/Downloads/jdk1.8.0_191/bin` is not a valid identifier.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Also, how did you add the dark grey background edit to my original post? That was really helpful